# Why do .bss/.rodata symbols stay in binary after strip?

Tags: c, gcc, ffmpeg, linker, elf

As far as I know, there's only one kind of symbols in executable binary that is really needed, which is **dynamic symbols**. These symbols is used in relocation operation because they are dynamic linked. Static linked functions/variables, in the other hand, is not needed so can be stripped.

However, when I was examining the **stripped** `ffmpeg` binary, this is what I got:

```
>nm -D ffmpeg
...
                 U __vfprintf_chk
                 U __vsnprintf_chk
                 U write
00000000018fa880 B x264_cabac_contexts
0000000001052a40 R x264_cabac_range_lps
0000000001052940 R x264_cabac_transition
0000000001970580 B x264_cabac_transition_unary
0000000001056820 R x264_last_coeff_flag_offset
0000000001056860 R x264_significant_coeff_flag_offset
0000000001056900 R x264_significant_coeff_flag_offset_8x8
                 U __xpg_strerror_r
                 U __xstat64
...
```

I can verify that libx264 is **static linked** to ffmpeg:

```
> ldd ffmpeg
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff26d61000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7c707e7000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7c704e1000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f7c702be000)
libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f7c700ae000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f7c6fe95000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7c6fc76000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7c6f8b0000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7c70b0a000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7c6f69a000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7c6f495000)
```

So, I don't understand why symbols like `x264_cabac_contexts` is not stripped. (It's defined in libx264/.../cabac.c):

```
uint8_t x264_cabac_contexts[4][QP_MAX_SPEC+1][1024];
```

It bothered me for several hours and I've found nothing on google... Hope someone would explain this... Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you look closer (and print out the actual sections) you will see that the BSS section takes no space in the file, only in memory. It's also the section that contains uninitialized data for e.g. global variables. For example, if you have an array `int X[SOME_SIZE];`, the space for that array will be in the BSS segment.  The RODATA segment is for Read-Only initialized data, for example string literals will probably end up in this section, or a global constant array like e.g. `const char Name[] = "Foobar";`.

Comment: In short, if you remove those sections then you also remove data that is needed by the program to work.

Comment: In addition to the above, you seem concerned about why that symbol is still visible: Pretty sure the linkage on that symbol would be the default, which is external, which means it falls under what you call "dynamic symbols". Perhaps it should not be external, but the compiler can't know that unless you tell it this (by using `static` for example).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for your reply! Yes I understand that .bss section is used for uninitialized global data and .rodata section is used for constant, but my questions is that why is the **variable names** (symbols) remains in binary as it's already stripped and static linked?

Comment: @DarkFalcon That's exactly what bothers me. External symbols should be visible on .o files but can be stripped in executable binary, am I right?

Comment: What would happen, for example, if `liblzma` or even something loaded with `dlopen` later were to use that symbol? Note that `-rdynamic` controls this for executables to some degree. Are you compiling with or without it?

Comment: No, I'm not compiling it with `-rdynamic`

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, there's only one kind of symbols in executable binary that is really needed, which is **dynamic symbols**.

Correct.

> So, I don't understand why symbols like x264_cabac_contexts is not stripped.

Because they are **dynamic symbols** (that's exactly what `nm -D` is printing).

The question you should be asking is not why the dynamic symbols aren't stripped, but why is `x264_cabac_contexts` a dynamic symbol.

There are two likely answers:

1. either the `ffmpeg` binary was linked with `--export-dynamic` or equivalent flag, or
2. the symbol was referenced by some shared library that participated in the link.

Looking at the list of shared libraries in `ldd` output, answer #2 seems unlikely. So answer #1 is probably correct.

> No, I'm not compiling it with -rdynamic

Compiling has nothing to do with this. It's *linking* that matters. You didn't show your link command, but it probably has *some* flag which means "export all symbols" (i.e. is equivalent to `-rdynamic`). Or you use a linker script that does the same.

Answer (score 0):

What?

If you have actual constant read-only data in your code, e.g.

```
const char *serialNumber = "451722-145252";
```

then of course that has to live somewhere, and if you strip it you break the program so that can't be removed.

If `serialNumber` here isn't `static`, then it can't be removed.

Comment: Yes I understand that "451722-145252" should be in binary but why is "serialNumber" (the symbol)?